# Chamar AJAX / jquery no meio do código PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tenho uma estrutura de código PHP e, dentro dela, quero chamar de forma automática um `$.get` AJAX para uma outra página PHP.

Exemplo:

```
<?php $cod = 1; $mod = 2; $text = 3; 
como chamar um ajax automaticamente aqui, sem ter que clicar em botão algum, conforme exemplo abaixo:
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    $.get('../print.php?cod =$cod&mod=$mod&text=text');
</script>"
//continuo com o código php
$bla = 1; $bla2 = 2; etc..... `
```

Ou seja.. no meio no meu *script* PHP que quero chamar via AJAX um outro *script* de impressão que irá mandar uma outra rotina e continuar na minha rotina da pagina mãe.

Não sei se fui claro, mas preciso de ajuda.

Comment: Você não conseguirá fazer isso. O PHP roda no servidor e o JavaScript no cliente. De certa forma isso até poderia funcionar, mas a requisição AJAX só iria ocorrer quando o navegador executasse o JavaScript. Se precisa fazer uma requisição HTTP com o PHP, utilize a biblioteca cURL.

Comment: Cara, você é um gênio. Fiquei tão focado no ajax que esqueci completamente que podia chamar pelo cURL já que já estava no php.
Muuuuittoo Obrigado :)

Comment: Olá DvD. A título de estudo, pode simular um exemplo? Agradeço :)

Comment: @DvD Utilizar AJAX dentro de um `echo` não é o mesmo que efetuar uma requisição AJAX no PHP. O que é impresso pelo `echo` fará parte do corpo da resposta HTTP que o servidor enviará e só será processada no cliente. Se a requisição precisa ser feito no lado do servidor, isso não resolverá o problema, como bem comentei.

Comment: Coloque esse código numa página PHP: `<?php echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('olá');</script>";?>` e veja o resultado... da mesma forma que vc consegue dar um `alert` em JS, vc pode chamar um Ajax

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Entendi agora. Ele quer chamar um Ajax PHP dentro de um script JS. Foi mal. :)

Comment: Não, só quer fazer uma requisição HTTP para outro arquivo PHP. Não tem porque ter AJAX/JS aqui.

Comment: Exatamente. Fiquei tão focado em uma possível solução que não pensei no simples. Ao postar aqui, vocês olharam com uma ótica externa e já abriram a minha mente. O cURL resolveu de imediato a minha situação. Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Se for PHP com PHP talvez nem precise do cURL. Muitas vezes um include/require resolve, ou mesmo execução agendada por crontab ou agendador de tarefas.

Comment: NovatodaWeb, se possível, responda sua pergunta colocando como resolveu o problema. Como o Bacco disse, talvez nem precise efetuar outra requisição.

Comment: Imagine o cenário. Estou no meio de uma série de processos (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i ..)
No meio do processamento, na opção D por exemplo, vem uma resposta de uma consulta sql falando que eu tenho que fazer um novo procedimento antes de continuar o restante do processamento, como por exemplo, uma impressão.
O que eu fiz, foi quando esta resposta voltar true, eu faço uma chamada via cURL (substituindo a tentativa em ajax) para um outro script rodar aquele processo e depois eu termino o restante do processamento que estava fazendo, sem ter que sair do script e retornar, entenderam?

Answer (score 0):

O objetivo do ajax é necessariamente fazer um requisição assíncrona, para casos em que você dependa de dados do usuário e/ou fazer carregamento de informações somente quando necessário, sem ter que atualizar a pagina por completo. E é obrigatório que para ser um ajax essa chamada seja feita pela linguagem front, e só é executada depois que a pagina já foi montada pelo PHP.

Acredito que o que você queria fazer e apenas incluir mais código para processar no servidor, para isso basta dar um include do arquivo PHP que você queira executar.

Lembre que ao contrario do Javascript  o PHP é uma linguagem síncrona e só ira executar o próximo comando quando o anterior terminar náo sendo possível fazer um ajax de php para php.

Espero ter ajudado.